# JS snippet which is coming as an AJAX response not getting executed

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I've a php page which returns a full-fledge js snippet when we query that page. Let say that page is get_js.php and looks something like this:

```
<?php
echo '<script>alert("hey");</script>';
?>
```

The ask here is that the value returned by that get_js.php should be executed on client side when we do an ajax call. The echo string above is just an example and can be any other js snippet like `<script>document.getElementById("this_div_id_exists").style.display = "none";</script>`.

The client side implementation is something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'get_js.php',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
        document.getElementById("this_div_id_exists").innerHTML = data;
    }
});
```

If I check the Elements tab from DevTools, the data is appended inside the proper div.

PS: there's no issue with retrieving the data as console.log works fine. And also guys this project is far from refactoring process, hence settling down the workaround.

Comment: The above code should work just fine too. It's just that the external JS was messing with the logic in my machine. I've accepted @Kinglish answer's because his solution of calling eval() makes more sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `eval()`

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'get_js.php',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
        document.getElementById("this_div_id_exists").innerHTML = data;
        // now loop through any script tags and eval() them
        document.querySelectorAll("#this_div_id_exists script").forEach(tag => eval(tag.innerHTML));
    }
});
```

Comment: Umm.... this looks promising but isn't really working in my machine. Can you just help me with jsfiddle ? @Kinglish

Comment: @RupeshBhandari - I was missing something, updated my answer `eval(tag.innerHTML)`, not just `eval(tag)`

Answer (score 1):

Would it not make more sense to keep JS in the JS?

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(['message' => 'hey']);
```

Now, you can alert the message directly in the requests response rather than inject it into the DOM.

```
fetch('get_js.php', { method: 'POST' })
.then(resp => resp.json())
.then(resp => {
    alert(resp.message);
});
```

Comment: I totally agree with you @Jaquarh, it's just that this application is developed by someone else and is in very poor state. Honestly, I really can't sit and refactor things now. But anyways thanks for your answer but this still doesn't answer my question. How about you return a js snipped inside message and try to execute that ? let say `"message" => "<script>alert('alert')</script>"`. Also I'm sending a full js snippet so that I can put it inside any div's id

Comment: Your question is not clear. Provide a [minimal, complete and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You're adding points in your comments that do not exist in the question. @RupeshBhandari